# UI problems in IOS 9 - cordova

Tags: ios, css, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building a cordova based app using ionic framework. We tested the app in browser and android. It is working well but when I try in iphone with recent version of IOS, all the ui is distorted. How do I avoid or solve this ui distortion issue?

[image: Iphone screenshot]

[image: browser screenshot]

Comment: that happens when you activate the personal hotspot, it moves the screen

Comment: In my case I'm using the emulator. I don't think that's the reason either.